# Buscar un Objeto de un Array Http con pipe Angular2

Tags: angular

Quiero realizar una solicitud http a un Json y esto me devuelve un array de comentarios, de ese Array quiero sacar directamente los comentarios que tengan un Id que coincida con el que le paso, todo ello directamente:

```
export class DetailUserComponent implements OnInit {

  comments: Comments[];


  constructor(
    private conexionComment: ConexionCommentsService) { }

   ngOnInit() {
         this.conexionComment.getCommentsPerson(0)
              .subscribe(comments => this.comments = comments);
  }
```

---

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { Comments } from './Class/comments';

@Injectable()
export class ConexionCommentsService {
  comments: Comments[];

  constructor( private http: HttpClient) { }

  getCommentsPerson(id: number): Observable<Comments[]> {
    const url = 'assets/Json/listComment.json';
    return this.http.get<Comments[]>(url).pipe(find(myComment => this.comments.idUser === id));
  }
```

La idea es mediante el pipe encontrar en el Array de objetos, el objeto.idUser === a la id que paso '0'
El problema es que al poner this.comments.YA no tengo acceso a los atributos del objeto

Comment: De dónde sale esa función `find`?

Comment: cuando escribo la f te la da como autocompletado y no da error en esa parte, y supongo que al usar el pipe, lo cogerá como de ahí, no lo sé , soy nuevo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La manera más sencilla de filtrar un array es usando su método `filter`:

```js
let users=[];

for (let i=5;i<40;i+=5) {
  users.push({idUser:i, name: 'user'+i});
}

//Tenemos estos usuarios
users.forEach(u=> console.log(u.name,u.idUser));

let filtered=users.filter(u => u.idUser>10 && u.idUser<30);
console.log('Después de filtrar')
filtered.forEach(u=> console.log(u.name,u.idUser));
```

Si aplicas find al observable o a su Stream (que es lo que obtienes en  la función `pipe()`), filtrará dicho observable, no su contenido: Es decir, si el observable te devuelve un array, filter puede dejarlo pasar o no, pero no parte de él.

Sumando todo esto:

```
getCommentsPerson(id: number): Observable<Comments[]> {
  const url = 'assets/Json/listComment.json';
  const result=this.http.get<Comments[]>(url);
  return result.map((comments: Comments[]) => {
    return comments.filter(myComment => myComment.idUser === id);
  }
}
```

Comment: como hago entonces para lanzar el observable, filtrar y después retornar los objetos que me interesan, es que en el return siemper me dice que no es de tipo observable porque no hago el return this.http . cosa que como voy a retornar un array finalmente no hay this.http

Comment: Te he añadido el método

Comment: Gracias,muchas gracias